# В биосе не видно Grub

Tags: linux, grub

После установки Kali Linux на весь жёсткий диск в биосе не оказалось загрузчика. Попробовал восстановить Grub перезаписав его в MVR, но понял что для перезаписи в MVR нужны две системы. Так что теперь не знаю что делать.

Comment: а в биосе не должно оказаться. граб - это загрузчик. а биос стартует загрузчик. что за  ошибку вынаблюдаете?